# Domain and service methods for banking transaction

Tags: spring, domain-driven-design

I am trying to learn Spring framework and see the many of the examples use domain and service objects (domain-driven design?) but I am not able to really understand how to arrive at them. For example, I am trying to model a simple banking application which has customers,accounts and transactions.  Below is the draft model i have:

```
Domain objects:
     Customer
         id
         userName
         password
     Account:
         id
         customerId
         balance
     Transaction:
         id
         accountId
         amount
         transactionDate
         transactionType

Service objects:
     AccountService:
         create(Account)
         update(Account)
         debit(Account,amount,date,remarks)
         credit(Account,amount,date,remarks)
         transfer(fromAccount,toAccount,amount,remarks)
         findAccountsByCustomerId(customerId)?
     CustomerService:
         findCustomerByName()
         findAccountsByCustomerId(customerId)?
```

1. Should the CustomerService or AccountService have the method findAccountsByCustomerId(customerId)?
2. Which domain/service objects should represent the debit/credit transaction? debit() and credit() methods in Account domain object to be defined or in the service object? I would like to persist the transactions rather than just updating the balance.
3. Should all the business logic be in Service layer? I see most of the spring examples out there are this way.

Comment: If your object can "anwser" your needs, then it should be in your model as it is domain driven. If the problem is about context (time, check against external systems etc) then it can only be done in services (or you will have dependencies about external stuff in your model: you don't want that).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Since the idea here is to retrieve Accounts, it should be in
   AccountService.
2. Both methods looks fine in AccountService to me because you're
       operating on accounts. If you want to persist the transaction you
       could have a TransactionDao handling this for you and you'd be
       calling it from your AccountService each time you need it. Doing
       both in your AccountService methods will allow you to be
       transactional. You don't want to persist the transaction object if
       updating the balance raised an exception.
3. Services are useful when you have business logic which does not
       belong in your DAO layer. The latter is supposed to query your
       database and give you back appropriate domain objects whereas
       services are mostly used to do additional treatments like handling
       transactions or DTO mapping.

You should take a look at the official Spring sample app [PetClinic](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-petclinic/tree/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/samples/petclinic) to give you an idea.

Comment: Thanks @LMeyer, That helps a lot. In the PetClinic app, only one service (ClinicService) is defined which will process all the domain objects. So should I create just one service as BankService? Even complex applications to have only one service? Sorry, am new to this service/domain model and trying to understand their scope..

Comment: @Skar Not necessarily, PetClinic is a simple app so one service is fine and it's still coherent (after all a clinic does handle pets, vets and clients). However in more complex app, nothing prevents you from doing several services like now. Overall, just don't break the [SRP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle)